# Compare data received through GET with data in ACF checkbox field (query post if at least one match is found)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to build a custom wordpress search form. The data on my search page will be sent to my results page using GET method. This data will then be matched with data in ACF custom fields.

Everything is going well so far except for one particular field:

In my search form on the frontend I have a checkbox for colors, the data sent to my results page looks like this in the address bar:

```
&colors=blue,green
```

I then save this into a variable like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['colors'])) {
    $mycolors = $_GET['colors'];
}
```

Now, the problem comes in where I'm trying to query this in Wordpress. Each post has an ACF checkbox field where I select the available colors. And I want the post to be queried if at least one color matches. So if a post has "blue" and "yellow" selected in the ACF checkbox, and the data received via GET is "blue" and "green" then the post should be queried because it matches at least one color.

The below works as long as only ONE color was received via GET

```
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'my_color_field',
        'value' => $mycolors,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
  ) ,
```

The moment multiple colors are received then no posts are being queried.

I figured this was because the $mycolors variable is supposed to be an array, so I tried to convert it to an array like this:

```
$mycolorsList = explode(",",$mycolors);
```

I then replaced the variable in my query to the new variable I created. But this results in this kind of error:

*"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: addcslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string"*

How can I query posts if at least one color match is found between the data received via GET and the data entered via ACF checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add every color as a own relation.

```
$mycolorsList = explode(",",$mycolors);
$meta_array = array();

foreach ($mycolorslist as $key => $value) {
    array_push( $meta_array,
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'relate_blog_posts',
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    );
}

$post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => $meta_array
);
$post_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
```